# Sharing temporary files between users

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, permissions, temporary-files

I am building a web application deployment script in PowerShell, and for one task I am trying to create and restore a database from a Sql-Server backup file.

The files end up being in the user's desktop, so when I instruct Sql-Server to restore it, it complains with an 'Access is denied.' error when reading the backup.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Acme] FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\matthew\Desktop\my-database.bak' WITH REPLACE
```

Responds with

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\matthew\Desktop\my-database.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

Moving the file to a publicly accessible area like `C:\Temp` works, as indicated in the following answer: [Why can't I read from .BAK files on my Desktop using SQL Express in Windows Authentication Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242421/why-cant-i-read-from-bak-files-on-my-desktop-using-sql-express-in-windows-auth)

However, `C:\Temp` is not a standard Windows temp directory.  Since I am using PowerShell, I am leveraging .NET libraries, such as using [`GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This ends up pointing to

> C:\Users\matthew\AppData\Local\Temp

which still has the same permission problem.

Is there a standard way to get a temporary directory that any local user can access?

EDIT: to clarify, the user `matthew` and the user that is restoring the backup are different.

Comment: Users should always have write access to their own `Temp` directory. I would investigate why that would not be the case.

Comment: Which user is running the restore task? If it's a different user than matthew you may want to place the backup file in some other place that's publicly accessible (or at least accessible by a group the restore user is a member of). `C:\Users\Public\Documents` or `C:\Users\Public\Downloads` come to mind. Creating a temp directory `C:\Temp` also isn't uncommon.

Comment: The notion of "standard Windows directory" is kind of tenuous. Is not like Linux' "File Hierarchy Standard", where there's a clear standard. Folks have used c:\temp as a temp directory since MS-DOS 2.0, so it's pretty much as standard as it gets. The only pitfall I see is if C: is not the SystemDrive. But if you work in an IT org, where Windows desktops come from a common image(s) then that's solved. Alternatively you can use $env:HOMEDRIVE or $env:SYSTEMDRIVE to determine what drive to look for \TEMP on (or look on both).

Comment: I'd probably just use c:\Windows\temp, or just create a temp folder as part of the scrip and place the backup file there for all to access.

Comment: Good call everyone, I'll just make my own, do it simple.

Comment: Why don't you use `WITH MOVE` and put the data/log files in the proper default location rather than a user-specific folder?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am just specifying the backup location, the data/log files end up in the default location.

Comment: If these backup files are for a database that was backed up on a different system, this likely only works because the two systems have the same data/file locations. This won't always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon to create a folder `C:\Temp` as a system-wide temp directory. For a backup/restore scenario you just need a folder that's accessible by both the backup and the restore user, be it a custom folder, a built-in public folder like `C:\Users\Public\Documents`, or adjusted permissions on a userprofile.

However, from a security point of view it's probably a good idea to create a dedicated folder (e.g. `C:\backup`) to which only the required users have access, e.g. like this:

```
$backupDir   = 'C:\backup'
$backupUser  = 'DOMAIN\userA'
$restoreUser = 'DOMAIN\userB'

function New-Ace {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$User,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Access
  )

  New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($User, $Access,
    'ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
}

$dir = New-Item -Type Directory $backupDir

$acl = Get-Acl -Path $dir
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace -User $backupUser -Access 'Modify'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace -User $restoreUser -Access 'Read'))
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $dir
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, this is exactly what I need.